# Sublime Text reports syntax error when using Babel>Transform on a JSX file

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, babeljs

**The Symptom**
When I use Sublime Text's Tools > Babel > Transform on a `.jsx` file such as the following...

```
function ActionLink() {
  return (
    <a href="#">
      Click me
    </a>
  );
}
```

... I get a Syntax error due to the special JSX syntax:

```
Error: SyntaxError/home/ ... /test.jsx: Unexpected token (3:4)

  1 | function ActionLink() {
  2 |   return (
> 3 |     <a href="#">
    |     ^
  4 |       Click me
  5 |     </a>
  6 |   );
```

**The Details**
On Ubuntu 16.04, I'm setting up Sublime Text to work with React's JSX files. I understand that I need to have Babel installed to do this. When I used  Package Control: Install Package, the Babel package did not appear as an option, but when I use Preferences > Browse Packages, I see a Babel folder, so it appears to be already installed.

Through a terminal window, I ran the following commands.

```
$ sudo npm install -g babel
$ npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
$ npm install babel-core babel-loader --save-dev
$ npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx
```

I've ensured that the menu item `View > Syntax > Babel > JavaScript (Babel)` is checked for `.jsx` files, and code highlighting occurs as expected.

What steps have I missed?